# Components of Linear Regression Model

Tags: regression, probability

I think this is a rather silly doubt but would appreciate if someone helps me with this.

I am finding it difficult to understand the premise of the regression coefficient.If the data points shows the actual relationship between two variables,what data is used to estimate the components of the regression model to come up with the regression line.

It would be great to know an example of the kind of data used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If the data points shows the actual relationship between two variables" what do you mean by "shows?" That data was generated randomly from a supposedly true model, but it's still random. You can't see the "real" stuff--in other words, the data doesn't "show" the relationship in that sense.

Comment: By "shows" i meant represents. Now i understand that the data points are randomly generated to come up with the regression line, which can be based on a true model. Thanks